# sql запрос "boss"

Tags: sql, oracle

Необходимо создать запрос, выдающий 
значения dname, ename, строка 'boss' если зарплата сотрудника 
равна максимальной в этом отделе.
Уже имеется готовый код, но его нужно немного переделать:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT d.dname, e.ename, DENSE_RANK() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY e.deptno 
            ORDER BY e.sal DESC) boss 
      FROM emp e, dept d 
      WHERE e.deptno = d.deptno) 
WHERE boss = 1;
```

Требуется отобразить все записи, где в отдельном поле будет или не будет появляться значение "boss". Но мой запрос выводит сразу боссов. Всю голову уже сломал. Надеюсь на совет более опытных sql-программистов.

Comment: Т.е. выводим всех сотрудников, если у человека максимальная зарплата в отделе - выводим `boss`, если не максимальная - выводим пустую строку или `null`? Я правильно понял задачу?

Comment: Совершенно верно

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо за понятные разъяснения в выполнении задачи!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Убираем условие на `boss=1`. Это условие оставляет нам только "боссов", а нам нужны все.
2. Переписываем Добавляем поле, в котором будет выдаваться "босс" это или нет. Для этого используем `CASE`:

   ```
   SELECT dname, ename, case when boss=1 then 'boss' else null end as boss
   FROM (SELECT d.dname, e.ename, DENSE_RANK() 
     OVER (PARTITION BY e.deptno 
           ORDER BY e.sal DESC) boss 
     FROM emp e, dept d 
     WHERE e.deptno = d.deptno) bs;
   ```

Comment: Ваш вариант более верен. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

1) Находишь максимальную зарплату в отделе. Например:

`wages` - значение зарплаты, смотри поле в своих таблицах.
`your_table` - таблица, в которой есть поле с зарплатой.

```
SELECT max(wages) AS MAX_wages FROM your_table
```

2) Находишь все поля, связанные с этой зарплатой:

`yt` - сокращение для названия таблицы.
`myt` - сокращение для таблицы с максимальным значением.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table AS yt
JOIN (SELECT max(wages) AS MAX_wages FROM your_table
) AS myt ON myt.MAX_wages = yt.wages
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция `DENSE_RANK()` ранжирует сотрудников по зарплате, а `PARTITION BY e.deptno` в вашем запросе начинает нумерацию заново для каждого отдела. Далее во внешнем запросе условие `WHERE boss = 1` оставляет только одного сотрудника с самой большой зарплатой в отделе, то есть ровно то, что вы просите. Количество строк в итоге должно соответствовать количеству отделов.
Если вам надо выводить всех, то уберите условие `WHERE boss = 1` во внешнем запросе, а для пометок `boss` сделайте дополнительное вычисляемое поле:

```
SELECT *, decode(boss, 1, 'boss', null) boss
FROM (SELECT d.dname, e.ename, DENSE_RANK() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY e.deptno 
            ORDER BY e.sal DESC) boss 
      FROM emp e, dept d 
      WHERE e.deptno = d.deptno)
```